# My Function Won't Be Called When I Have An Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

For some reason, my function won't be called, and this is the way I've been doing it since I started!

```
<h1 id="c"></h1>
<button onClick="new()">n</button>
<script>
    var end = document.getElementById('c');

    var a = ['ur mom', 'The Illuminati', 'A door', 'That shady guy on the corner of the street', 'Windows xp', 'Spodermen', 'Murica', 'Barack Obama', 'Patrick Star', 'Justin Bieber', 'The Game Grumps', 'Pewdiepie', 'A FLUFFY BUNNY'];

    var aX = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)]

    function new() {
        end.innerHTML = aX;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword. Probably shouldn't be using that for a function name.

Comment: Well ok then, MINDFART. I remembeer running into this problem a while ago..

Answer (score 1):

`new` is a reserved keyword in javascript and you cannot use it as a function signature. Change the name of your method and the code will work.

```
<button onClick="myMethod()">n</button>
```

and

```
function myMethod() {
        end.innerHTML = aX;
    }
```

See this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q2fL7aah/)